# How do I get advanced API calls added to my app?

Tags: linkedin-api

I am trying to get the below calls added to my app in my #LinkedIn developer account but can't get any response from support and all of the forms don't do anything. Any help is appreciated!

v2/socialActions @GET
v2/shares @GET
v2/invitation @POST

I filled out the form on the LinkedIn Developer site, I reached out to LI support, and they sent me to Stackoverflow.